# How to import and reference other class in sublime?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I want to build a plugin that uses the default git-sublime classes and methods.

In the Git-plugin a method is used like this:

```
   def run(self):
        self.run_command(['git', 'branch', '--no-color'] + self.extra_flags, self.branch_done)
```

it's imported like this:

```
from git import GitTextCommand, GitWindowCommand, git_root_exist
```

`run_command` is defined in another classs in a file named git.py, like this:

```
class GitCommand(object):
    may_change_files = False

    def run_command(self, command, callback=None, show_status=True,
            filter_empty_args=True, no_save=False, **kwargs):
        if filter_empty_args:
            command = [arg for arg in command if arg]
        if 'working_dir' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['working_dir'] = self.get_working_dir()
        if 'fallback_encoding' not in kwargs and self.active_view() and self.active_view().settings().get('fallback_encoding'):
            kwargs['fallback_encoding'] = self.active_view().settings().get('fallback_encoding').rpartition('(')[2].rpartition(')')[0]

        s = sublime.load_settings("Git.sublime-settings")
        if s.get('save_first') and self.active_view() and self.active_view().is_dirty() and not no_save:
            self.active_view().run_command('save')
        if command[0] == 'git' and s.get('git_command'):
            command[0] = s.get('git_command')
        if command[0] == 'git-flow' and s.get('git_flow_command'):
            command[0] = s.get('git_flow_command')
        if not callback:
            callback = self.generic_done

        thread = CommandThread(command, callback, **kwargs)
        thread.start()

        if show_status:
            message = kwargs.get('status_message', False) or ' '.join(command)
            sublime.status_message(message)
...
```

Does from git reference the file git.py?

Is the import related to the class gitCommand and in that case how?

I have tried to import run_command in my own repo like this:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, subprocess, os, time, sys, re
from git import GitTextCommand, GitWindowCommand, git_root_exist

class PanagoraBuildCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand, sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, edit):

        self.run_command(['git', 'branch' '--no-color'], self.branch_done)
```

but it says `AttributeError: 'PanagoraBuildCommand' object has no attribute 'run_command'`, why?

Comment: I tried gitCommand.run_command instead but got an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is in:

```
class PanagoraBuildCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand, sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
```

You should inherit the GitWindowCommand here

```
class PanagoraBuildCommand(GitWindowCommand):
```